# Can you name a set of criteria if a number of sets satisfy the criteria?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm trying to set out a definition that involves a function from any set that meets these criteria: $ \langle p| p\in\mathbb{R}\ \land p \geq0 \, \, \land \sum p= 1 \rangle$

(I've only used sigma notation with some information about the extreme values, but according to what I read online, $ \sum p$ means the sum of every $p$.)

I'd like to name 'that' set. However, given that more than one set fulfills those criteria, if I were to use $ P = $, I could infer a contradiction.

How do I name $P$?

Comment: I would guess "Let $P$ be a set of non-negative real numbers which sum to $1$" is what you're looking for - but it's not particularly clear how you're hoping to use this.

Comment: I'm trying to write a proof about expected utility (weighted averages) that if the utility of every possible outcome of every possible action is the same then the expected utility of every action is the same. It's easy if your prof allows you to use some english and references to common knowledge. However, ours wants everything proven validly with natural deduction and elementary algebra. So I'm trying to define expected value in a way that let's me refer to its different aspects in my proof.

Comment: In my question, I'm trying to characterize the set of probabilities used in any weighted average.

Comment: That's a strange request of a proof - but, in any case, however you formalize it, you need to be clear that $P$ is *a* set subject to certain constraints - that is, you are *not* constructing it, because there is no unique choice of "the set". That is, you want to prove a statement of the form $$\text{$P$ satisfies these hypothesis} \Longrightarrow \text{Some conclusions}$$
rather than offering any construction of $P$. So, you might just take:
$$P\subset \mathbb R$$
$$\forall p\in P[p\geq 0]$$
$$\sum p = 1$$
as givens, and prove whatever you want from them.